# Чтение из xml файла и запись во все TextBox на форме

Tags: c#, winforms, xml

У меня на форме 6 разных tabPage на которых расположены по 12 пар textBox и 12 label.

Записываю в xml файл данные вот этим способом

```
//Запись данных в xml файл
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
XElement xroot = new XElement("Database");

//Запись из каждого Label и TextBox
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    XElement Accounts = new XElement("Account");
    XAttribute ID = new XAttribute("ID", i.ToString());
    XElement Name = new XElement("name", tabPage1.Controls["name" + i.ToString()].Text);
    XElement Login = new XElement("login", tabPage1.Controls["login" + i.ToString()].Text);
    XElement Password = new XElement("password", tabPage1.Controls["password" + i.ToString()].Text);
    Accounts.Add(ID);
    Accounts.Add(Name);
    Accounts.Add(Login);
    Accounts.Add(Password);
    xroot.Add(Accounts);
}

xDoc.Add(xroot);
xDoc.Save("data.xml");
```

На выходе получается xml файл со следующим содержимым

```
<Database>
  <Account ID="1">
    <name>noname</name>
    <login></login>
    <password></password>
  </Account>
  <Account ID="2">
    <name>noname</name>
    <login></login>
    <password></password>
  </Account>
...
</Database>
```

Как из этого файла прочитать и вывести обратно в Label и TextBoxы на форме?

Пробую вот так, но пока не выходит.

```
//Загрузка данных из xml файла
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
foreach (XElement Accounts in xDoc.Element("Database").Elements("Account"))
{               
    XAttribute ID = Accounts.Attribute("ID");
    XElement Name = Accounts.Element("name");
    XElement Login = Accounts.Element("login");
    XElement Password = Accounts.Element("password");

    if (Name != null && Login != null && Password != null)
    { 
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            tabPage1.Controls["name"+i.ToString()].Text = Name.Value;
            tabPage1.Controls["login" + i.ToString()].Text = Login.Value;
            tabPage1.Controls["password" + i.ToString()].Text = Password.Value;
        }
    }               
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте изучить, что такое сериализация и десереализация XML.

Comment: Если у вас используется множество (12) однотипных данных, то не лучше ли использовать DataGridView для них? Вместо кучи лейблов и текстбоксов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, контролы на форме расположены следующим образом:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TabControl tabControl1;

    public Form1()
    {
        //InitializeComponent();
        Width = 800;
        tabControl1 = new TabControl { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top, Height = 200 };

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) // 6
        {
            var tabPage = new TabPage { Parent = tabControl1, Name = "tabPage" + i };

            for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) // 12
            {
                var groupBox = new GroupBox { Parent = tabPage, Left = (j - 1) * 250, Height = 150 };

                var labelName = new Label { Parent = groupBox, Name = "name" + j, Top = 20, Text = $"noname{i}_{j}" };
                var textBoxLogin = new TextBox { Parent = groupBox, Name = "login" + j, Top = 60, Text = $"nologin{i}_{j}" };
                var textBoxPassword = new TextBox { Parent = groupBox, Name = "password" + j, Top = 100, Text = $"nopass{i}_{j}" };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В каждом `TabPage` несколько `GroupBox`. Каждый из этих групбоксов содержит `Label` и `TextBox`, что представляет один аккаунт.
Использование `GroupBox` для объединения контролов, относящихся к одному аккаунту важно, т. к. позволяет использовать их как единое целое. Это упрощает и получение данных из них, и последующее занесение данных в них.

---

Теперь запись в xml можно сделать так:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
XElement root = new XElement("Database");

int id = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabPages.Count; i++)
{
    var tabPage = tabControl1.TabPages[i];
    XElement page = new XElement("Page");

    var groupBoxes = tabPage.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().ToList();
    for (int j = 1; j <= groupBoxes.Count; j++)
    {
        var groupBox = groupBoxes[j - 1];

        page.Add(
            new XElement("Account",
                new XAttribute("ID", id),
                new XElement("name", groupBox.Controls["name" + j].Text),
                new XElement("login", groupBox.Controls["login" + j].Text),
                new XElement("password", groupBox.Controls["password" + j].Text)
            ));

        id++;
    }
    root.Add(page);
}

doc.Add(root);
doc.Save("data.xml");
```

Что тут происходит: проходим циклом по коллекции `TabPages`. Вторым циклом проходим по всем `GroupBox` внутри `TabPage`. Лейблы и текстбоксы получаем по имени.

Нумерация `id` сквозная. При желании можно её изменить.

Итоговый xml выглядит так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Database>
  <Page>
    <Account ID="1">
      <name>noname1_1</name>
      <login>nologin1_1</login>
      <password>nopass1_1</password>
    </Account>
    <Account ID="2">
      <name>noname1_2</name>
      <login>nologin1_2</login>
      <password>nopass1_2</password>
    </Account>
    <Account ID="3">
      <name>noname1_3</name>
      <login>nologin1_3</login>
      <password>nopass1_3</password>
    </Account>
  </Page>
  <Page>
    <Account ID="4">
      <name>noname2_1</name>
      <login>nologin2_1</login>
      <password>nopass2_1</password>
    </Account>
    ...
  </Page>
  <Page>
    <Account ID="7">
      <name>noname3_1</name>
      <login>nologin3_1</login>
      <password>nopass3_1</password>
    </Account>
    ...
  </Page>
  ...
</Database>
```

---

Теперь получение данных.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
int i = 0;
foreach (XElement page in doc.Element("Database").Elements("Page"))
{
    var tabPage = tabControl1.TabPages[i];
    var groupBoxes = tabPage.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().ToList();

    int j = 1;
    foreach (var account in page.Elements("Account"))
    {
        XAttribute id = account.Attribute("ID");
        XElement name = account.Element("name");
        XElement login = account.Element("login");
        XElement password = account.Element("password");

        var groupBox = groupBoxes[j - 1];

        groupBox.Controls["name" + j].Text = name.Value;
        groupBox.Controls["login" + j].Text = login.Value;
        groupBox.Controls["password" + j].Text = password.Value;

        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Получаем из xml элементы `Page` и заносим их в соответствующие `TabPage`.
Каждому элементу `Account` соответствует `GroupBox`.

---

Честно говоря, я бы выкинул всю эту мешанину и использовал один `DataGridView` вместо десятков текстбоксов и лейблов. И использовал сериализацию и привязку данных.

Comment: Данные записываются только в первых контролах, а дальше ничего.

Comment: @neobot - в чём причина была? Разобрались?

Comment: Я понял, что у меня проблема из за того, что контролы располагаются на разных tabPage. И при попытке перебора каждого из них для записи из xml файла возникает ошибка.

Comment: @neobot - значит и в коде создания xml ошибка. Тот код вообще работает?

Comment: У меня на форме 6 разных tabPage на которых расположены по 12 пар textBox и 12 label. Данные из них 6ю циклами считываются в xml файл. С этим проблем нет. А вот обратно из xml файла уже сложности. Если каждый элемент по отдельности записывать и читать, то получится большой код, а я хочу упростить. Ваш совет помог. На первом tabPage все записывается. Мне осталось только разобраться как записывать в остальные tabPage.